# POST @RequestParam Map<String, String> in Spring MVC returns empty map

Tags: spring, post, parameters, request-mapping

I have the following method:

```
@Controller
public class InterfaceController extends MasterController
{
    @PostMapping(value = "/interface") 
    @ResponseBody
    public String incomingPost(@RequestParam Map<String, String> queryMap)
    {
        System.out.println("Map: " + new Gson().toJson(queryMap));
        return "Raw string to return.";
    }
}
```

When I make a POST request to `/interface`, I get a successful 200 response with the dummy string I want to return with but the Map is not populated with my parameters:

```
Map: {}
```

Why?

Comment: how r u calling this endpoint can u show the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@RequestParam works if you pass all your params as part of url.

If you are passing the data in request body, then you must use

```
@RequestBody Map<String, Object> queryMap
```

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. I was posting in the body instead of x-www-form-urlencoded.